# How to get the value of an attribute of an array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, arrays, asp.net-web-api

I am new to AngularJS. I am getting data from SQL to AngularJS. I am able to display the data in ng-repeat but I want to get the value of a certain attribute of the array that I am passing from the database in my controller to use it in other functions.

Below is the controller where I get the data. $scope.candidates stores the whole data of Candidates in an array. I only want to get first names. is there anything like $scope.candidates.Firstname?

```
app.controller('CandidateCtrl', ['$scope', 'CandidateService',
    // we inject CandidatetService  inject becuse we call getAll method for get all student  
function ($scope, CandidateService) {
    // this is base url   
    var baseUrl = '/api/Candidate/';
    // get all candidate from databse  
    $scope.getCandidates = function () {
        var apiRoute = baseUrl + 'GetCandidates/';
        var _candidate = CandidateService.getAll(apiRoute);
        _candidate.then(function (response) {
            $scope.candidates = response.data;
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    }
    $scope.getCandidates();

}]);
```

Comment: You already fetched the entire data, just display the first name. If you wanna spare your network traffic, send only those back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you would have an element (a div in this example) with a ng-repeat on your collection. Then inside the div with ng-repeat, you would have another element (another div in this example) where you would access the property of a single item in your collection:

```
< div ng-repeat="candi in candidates">
    <div>{{candi.Firstname}}</div>
< /div>
```

If you want a collection of first names in JavaScript, you would use the map function:

```
var firstNames = $scope.candidates.map(function(c) { return c.Firstname; });
```